# How do I access PHP REST API PUT data on the server side?

Tags: php, rest, server-side, put

**-- Question --**

I am just starting out with the REST API and am getting pretty confused.

This is what my PHP cRUL client-side looks like for a PUT.

```
case 'PUT':
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    break;
```

Now when I look at the server my $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] shows PUT, but my question is how do I get the $data I sent with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

All I need to do is get the $data sent with a PUT request into the next line. Like

```
$value = $data['curl_data'];
```

I have seen so much clutter on this topic that it is giving me a headache. It seems so easy on the php client side, but no one has answers that are working for the php server side.

Thanks for any help!

**-- Answer (after help and homework) --**

*I am new so I can't answer my own question until after 8 hours... odd :)*

Okay, after working with the great people here I have to say we ran into the answer. I am kicking myself for it being so easy, at the same time it was confusing.

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

The first change (above) I had to add http_build_query() around $data. This took my data from an array to a url friendly string.

Next up I had to add.

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put);
```

Now I can do things like $put['data'].

The answer PaulPRO gave above does work to get the data the same way file_get_contents() did with less lines. We got stuck trying to figure out how to parse the data which was where my lack of http_build_query() I had seen on another site kicked into play.

So This is how it all works.

1. Data is put into a normal array.
2. http_build_query() converts it into a nice almost GET like string.
3. file_get_contents() transports it from the client to the server.
4. parse_str() then turns it back into an array.

I am seeing a lot of messages about using PUT to send files. I can see how this would work, but from what I read in this entire REST process was that PUT is to update data as post is to create data. Maybe I am mistaken. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe [these](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/2011/07/03/nobody-understands-rest-or-http.html) [links](http://quandyfactory.com/blog/65/designing_a_restful_web_application#toc_5.3) will help you better understand some of the quirks of REST.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php):

PUT data comes from stdin:

`$putdatafp = fopen("php://input", "r");`

Example usage:

```
$putfp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$putdata = '';
while($data = fread($putfp, 1024))
    $putdata .= $data;
fclose($putfp);
```

Comment: Okay got a lead with both of these. The upper one returned Resource #11. How do I access that resource. And the bottom returned the data in a messy string, but I see it is there.

Comment: @sylor I edited my post. Is the data correctly in `$putdata` after that code?

Comment: I am getting a few errors on the filesize. Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for Resource id #11. It also tells me that file size cant be 0 on fread.

Comment: @shylor Makes sense i guess, since stdin has a variable size. I think you'll have to do it with a loop then. I updated my post again.

Comment: If I use the file_get_contents I get this chunk of code... my data is in it, but how do I parse it? ------------------------------49d1750468a4 Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => \"app_secret\" a3e0701fbbafae60b9ba1922d0ee28def305113f ------------------------------49d1750468a4 Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\" email/1 ------------------------------49d1750468a4--

Comment: Your code will always cause infinite loop, since `$putdata` is always not empty after first iteration.

Comment: @shylor, you're right. That was a stupid overlooked error on my part. I fixed it.

Comment: Okay, I am now getting the same result from both systems. I just need to be able to parse that long mess of a string. Any ideas?

Comment: I need to get app_secret to = a3e0701fbbafae60b9ba1922d0ee28def305113f and data to = email/1

Comment: @Shylor, no idea. I'm thinking that looks like headers sent by a form POST request but I'm not sure how you'd read that in a PUT request. Have you tried making a PUT request to the page with just a number as input or something and no form data?

Comment: That is the data coming from opening the input. The data I need is there, just need to parse the junk off it to get it to something I can use.

Comment: Are you submitting an HTML form to make the request? I don't think that's normally how you make a PUT request.

Comment: Got a lead. I wrapped the data on the client with PHP http_build_query() and it does not look like a mess. It looks more like a GET now.app_secret=a3e0701fbbafae60b9ba1922d0ee28def305113f&data=email%2F1

Comment: @shylor Ah, that's perfect then. You should be able to use PHP's `parse_str()` function on it now: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Bingo got it. I will post up an official answer for all those that follow after me and scream. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 15):

I've the same scenario where in, have to send data to the PHP Server through ReST API using the PUT method. I struggled almost couple of hours to find the solution, but finally found the way :

**In CUrl :**

```
$postData = http_build_query($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);
```

We've to parse the data to a variable let say: $putData,
    Here, is the Parse String procedure :

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$putData);
```

Then print the `$putData`, will get the same array that you're posting in the curl..

Comment: This answer is the best way I like. `parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$putData); `

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get form data with key value like $_POST.

```
function PUT(string $name):string{

    $lines = file('php://input');
    $keyLinePrefix = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="';

    $PUT = [];
    $findLineNum = null;

    foreach($lines as $num => $line){
        if(strpos($line, $keyLinePrefix) !== false){
            if($findLineNum){ break; }
            if($name !== substr($line, 38, -3)){ continue; }
            $findLineNum = $num;
        } else if($findLineNum){
            $PUT[] = $line;
        }
    }

    array_shift($PUT);
    array_pop($PUT);

    return mb_substr(implode('', $PUT), 0, -2, 'UTF-8');

}
```

For Example **rest-api.php**

```
$title = PUT('title');
```