# proper way of PUT method usage with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working with some API that requires usage of PUT method. I am using pure Javascript with AJAX and PHP to get contents from API.

I found out that PUT method behaves a little bit different than GET or POST. One thing for example, you can access query parameters in GET or POST easily with $_GET or $_POST, in PUT method you can't do that.
So in my example I broke apart $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] in PUT method and put it into array and then read the parameters from it.

Just because of that I am wondering if there is anything special to be concirned about the PUT method?

I've read some articles, why it PUT method suppose to be used for, but there weren't any specific examples how to use it, especially in my cas with AJAX/PHP.

I made my code working like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $qstring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str($qstring, $qstring);
    if ($qstring['func'] == 'updatecart') {
        $query['sessid'] = intval($qstring['sessid']);
        $query['artikelid'] = $qstring['artikelid'];
        $query['velikostid'] = $qstring['velikostid'];
        $query['kolicina'] = intval($qstring['kolicina']);
        $resarr = getdatafromapi($method, $apibaseurl.'/kosarica', $query);
        echo json_encode($resarr);
        $query = array();
        exit;
    }
}
```

I just want to know if this is the correct way to use PUT method?

Comment: Please add some code to show your issue

Comment: I managed to make my code work, but here I am looking more of recommendations or "general rules" in cases like this.

I updated with the code.

Comment: @user3142368. Please post your code, so that great people may guide to creating greater code!

Comment: Questions without code and asking for recommendations are off topic - please visit [help]

Comment: @user3142368 You have to post the code showing your efforts. Otherwise you question should be closed as offtopic

Comment: Ok, I showed the code.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805570/how-do-i-access-php-rest-api-put-data-on-the-server-side)

Comment: Sorry, haven't found this one. It answers my question, but not as much because I have a different procedure. Thanks anyway.