# How do you get receive data with a PHP rest api?

Tags: php, rest, put

I am putting this data
{id="1", title="foo", imagedescription="bar"}

This is my PHP endpoint

```
<?php

// This will update a photo that has been edited
if (isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['title'], $_GET['imagedescription']))
{
$id=   $_GET['id'];
$title=  trim($_GET['title']);
$imagedescription=trim($_GET['imagedescription']);

require 'db_connect.php';

$update_query = "Update images Set title = {$title}, imagedescription = {$imagedescription} Where id={$id}";

    if($update = $db->query($update_query))
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Photo successfully updated.";
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response["failed"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
        $response["sql"] = $update_query;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}
else
{
// required field is missing
$response["failed"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

I just get {"failed":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"} with a 200 success response in Postman.

How do I get the data out of the request using PHP?

This is the Angular Service

```
(function () {
angular.module('app')
    .service('PhotosManager', ['$http', function($http) {

            this.getPhotos = function () {

                return $http.get("get_all_photos.php");
            };

            this.updatePhoto = function (id, data) {
                return $http.put("update_photo.php"+ id, data);

            };

    }]);

})();
```

I can see a successful response
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access PHP REST API PUT data on the server side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805570/how-do-i-access-php-rest-api-put-data-on-the-server-side)

Comment: you are putting this data `{id="1", title="foo", imagedescription="bar"}` got that. But from ajax or from rest client and is it GET or POST?

Comment: $http.put("update_photo.php"+ id, data);

Comment: Include the JS part so it can be more helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. First read the data that has been put, then json_decode it, finally you can access it from the array.

```
<?php


$putfp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$putdata = '';
while($data = fread($putfp, 1024))
$putdata .= $data;
fclose($putfp);


$data = json_decode($putdata, true);

// This will update a photo that has been edited
if (isset($data['id'], $data['title'], $data['imagedescription']))
{
$id=   $data['id'];
$title=  trim($data['title']);
$imagedescription=trim($data['imagedescription']);

require 'db_connect.php';

$update_query = "Update images Set title = '{$title}', imagedescription = '{$imagedescription}' Where id={$id}";

    if($update = $db->query($update_query))
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Photo successfully updated.";
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $response["failed"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
        $response["sql"] = $update_query;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

}
else
{
// required field is missing
$response["failed"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```