# PHP not reconizing data from jquery only in DELETE and PUT method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am a full stack student and trying to do my homework... i am sending to php  a object of daya with Jquery.
it's working fine when the method is GET or POST, but not working when it's DELETE & PUT, the php get's the methos but wouldn't get data object, it gives a error: Undefined index: activitiesArray.
i am using the same functions for all the options, and if i change the method it works.

PROBLEMS
OUTPUT
DEBUG CONSOLE
TERMINAL
..
what am i doing wrong??
thanks!

this is my ajax in javascript:
    "use static";

```
function sendAJAX(method, url, data, calltype) {
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: { activitiesArray: data },
        success: function(response_text) {
            callback(response_text, calltype);
        }

    });
}
```

and this is my php api:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; // verb
$params = $_REQUEST['activitiesArray'];

switch ($params['ctrl']) {
    case 'Director':
        $capi = new DirectorApi();
        $result  = $capi->gateway($method, $params);
        echo json_encode($result);

        break;
    case 'Movie':
    $capi = new MovieApi();
    echo $capi->gateway($method, $params);
    break;
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't parse and add data from PUT and DELETE requests into the `$_REQUEST`-array. You need to get the request body and parse out the data yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access PHP REST API PUT data on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805570/how-do-i-access-php-rest-api-put-data-on-the-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

change code like this for put and delete

```
function sendAJAX(method, url, data, calltype) {
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify({activitiesArray: data}),
        success: function(response_text) {
            callback(response_text, calltype);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'

    });
}
```

and on php side, you can't use $_REQUEST to handle put request, You can do like this

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; // verb
$params = $_REQUEST['activitiesArray'];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
    echo $post_vars['your_input']; // you can access query parameters like this

}
else
{
switch ($params['ctrl']) {
    case 'Director':
        $capi = new DirectorApi();
        $result  = $capi->gateway($method, $params);
        echo json_encode($result);

        break;
    case 'Movie':
    $capi = new MovieApi();
    echo $capi->gateway($method, $params);
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: jQuery always stringify the data for you that's getting sent, regardless of method, so adding `JSON.stringify()` is not necessary.