# how get post data from ajax method put

Tags: jquery, ajax

i try to get data in my php from a call ajax :

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data: {param: "param" },
  success: function(data) {
    alert('ok');
  }
});
```

but in my php $_POST['param'] is undefined

```
<?php   
    $param = $_POST['param'];
?>
```

Where i failed ?

Edit : SOLVED

in data i just need to add 'json.stringify' and that worked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access PHP REST API PUT data on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805570/how-do-i-access-php-rest-api-put-data-on-the-server-side)

Answer (score 1):

You have decode json

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {param: "param" },
  success: function(data) {
    alert('ok');
  }
});

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
 echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Comment: thanks, but i need the method put, its not possible to get data from that method ?

Comment: i have try like this, but my data is empty

Comment: @Ygg69 what are you getting?

Comment: i get only '<pre>'
Edit : i forgotten to add the datatype..i have try with this but now my ajax is not sucess but error